# Replacing text with jQuery goes wrong with multiple links

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, dynamic, replace

I am using the following code in a list of links to translate their title according to the language the user is pointing to. If the user is pointing, for example, to the Chinese language icon, the "article-title" gets replaced with its Chinese version. On mouse off, the title goes back to English. This works just fine.

Where I am running into problems: sometimes I need to add another link after the "article-title", on the same line. Whenever I do this, the script panics and flicks  the title between blank and default, because it is finding a link, but it's not telling it to change anything.

How do I add exceptions to this script? How do I make it check to see if the link has the class "foo", and if it does, please just ignore it?

```
$.each($("li"), function(i, elements) {
        var links = elements.getElementsByTagName("a");
        var article_title = elements.getElementsByClassName("article-title")[0];
        $.each(links, function(j, link) {
            var previous_title = article_title.innerHTML;
            link.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
                $(article_title).fadeTo(200, 0.5, function(){
                    article_title.innerHTML = link.title;
                    $(article_title).fadeTo(200, 1, function(){});
                });
            });
            link.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
                $(article_title).fadeTo(300, 0.5, function(){
                    article_title.innerHTML = previous_title;
                    $(article_title).fadeTo(300, 1, function(){});
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has a built in function called `hasClass(className)`. Simply use that to see if the `a` element has that particular class.

```
$.each($("li"), function(i, elements) {
        var links = elements.getElementsByTagName("a");
        var article_title = elements.getElementsByClassName("article-title")[0];
        $.each(links, function(j, link) {
            var previous_title = article_title.innerHTML;
            if (!$(link).hasClass("foo")) {
                link.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
                    $(article_title).fadeTo(200, 0.5, function(){
                        article_title.innerHTML = link.title;
                        $(article_title).fadeTo(200, 1, function(){});
                    });
                });
                link.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
                    $(article_title).fadeTo(300, 0.5, function(){
                        article_title.innerHTML = previous_title;
                        $(article_title).fadeTo(300, 1, function(){});
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Simply replace the class "foo" in the above example with the actual class name of links you wish to ignore.

Comment: Very clean solution! Thank you very much for the help.